# React Native Linking getInitialURL() is not working in android

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I am using Linking for Deep Links in React Native. When my app is in background I am able to get Deep Link URL from the listener method. But Linking getInitialURL() method always returns null when I am opening my app from another App. I am using React native v0.59.3. I tried downgrading the react-native version but the problem exists. Hope someone helps.

My Code

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
    console.warn(url); //returns null
    this.handleURL(url);
  });

Linking.addEventListener("url", this.handleURL);
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, what steps you took. I'm also facing the same problem on ReactNative v0.59.8.

Comment: I am able to solve the issue. It didn't work on changing the package name. I created a different project and left the package name as default. Then it worked!